# XSLT Number nodes without sorting

Tags: sorting, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following xml:

```
<policy>
    <games>
         <game startTime="11:00"/>
         <game startTime="11:20"/>
         <game startTime="11:40"/>
    </games>
    <games>
         <game startTime="11:10"/>
         <game startTime="11:30"/>
         <game startTime="11:50"/>
    </games>
</Policy>
```

I am trying to write an xslt that will add a new attribute to each game node and add the value in time order e.g.

```
<policy>
    <games>
         <game startTime="11:00" id="1"/>
         <game startTime="11:20" id="3"/>
         <game startTime="11:40" id="5"/>
    </games>
    <games>
         <game startTime="11:10" id="2"/>
         <game startTime="11:30" id="4"/>
         <game startTime="11:50" id="6"/>
    </games>
</policy>
```

I need the game nodes to stay in their current order so I'm not sure an xsl:sort would work.

At the moment I have this which obviously just numbers them in their current order and won't take account of the time attribute:

```
<xsl:template match="game">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::game) + 1"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Another question: are all time stamps generally destinct? Or is this only true for the example?

Comment: No I'm afraid it's 1.0 only.

Comment: There is a chance they might not be but i'm not too bothered how they end up being numbered if two are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace your match template by

```
<xsl:template match="game">
  <xsl:variable name="current_time" select="number(substring-before(@startTime,':'))*60 + number(substring-after(@startTime,':'))"/>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
      <xsl:value-of select="count(../../games/game[number(substring-before(@startTime,':'))*60 + number(substring-after(@startTime,':')) &lt; $current_time]) + 1"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

you will also get the desired result. This approach does not use sorting but for each entry counts all the entries below the current one. This was a really interesting task because I learnt the amazing fact today that *you cannot compare strings in XSLT 1.0*! Although the overall structure of your original template is maintained (as compared to the solution of @Rubens) it requires the time string to be converted into a number. Of course, this is inconvenient. However, you will probably have to add some extra string functionality to the other solution to make it robust with respect to times before 10:00 o'clock, too.

By the way: if time stamps occur multiple times the numbering corresponds to ranking with gaps (as opposed to a dense ranking without gaps).

Comment: Unfortunately although probably better than constantly doing sorts I'm not sure this will work with duplicated times. They end up with the same id being given.

Comment: That's what I meant by ranking with gaps. The performance implications are very similar since I would assume a `O(n^2)` portion for both solutions. In principle I would even assume that @Rubens' solution has `O(n^2*log(n))`. However, in both cases it's definitely something that you would not want to execute for large counts of `<game>`.

Comment: I suppose I could add an extra variable that counts the preceding nodes with the exact same time and add this to the original count.

Comment: There are probably ways but it will get uglier for sure. If you want I can look into this tonight.

Comment: Well I added a variable that counts preceding game nodes with the same start time and adds that to the count. It works so thanks for all your help. Would be interesting if there were any better ways.

Answer (score 2):

I hope there is a better way than this:

```
<xsl:template match="game">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="time" select="@startTime" />
        <xsl:for-each select="//game">
            <xsl:sort select="@startTime" />
            <xsl:if test="current()/@startTime = $time">
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Well it may not be elegant (having to select all nodes in the for loop) but it works, my pseudo xml should have contained a couple more attributes that can be used in the if statement. That helps get around the problem of duplicate times. Thanks v.much!